# Security Trimming for Wiki

Tags: wss-3.0, wiki, security-trimming

I am building a help wiki for my WSS 3.0 site. Each wiki page will explain a different feature about the site. It is written for the average user, with screenshots, etc. In addition, I want a matching wiki page that is written for the IT staff, that describes things on a technical level. I don't want the user to even see this link, as the technical information is not useful to the average user, and might be more confusing.

I am familiar with Security Trimming for the Navigation Bar and the Quick Launch (where SharePoint dynamically shows or hides links based on the current user's read permissions). Simply setting the permissions for the technical page will still show the link to a user, but shows an access denied error when they click the link. Is there a way to provide Security Trimming for wiki pages?